# Image to appear behind link with hover

Tags: html, css, hover

I found several related articles that helped, but I've hit a wall.

I have a menu nav with two things happening when the user hovers over a link: the link changes color and an image appears behind the link. Right now, the link is changing colors and the image is showing, but it's appearing in front of the text link. I can't figure out how to get the image to appear behind the text.

to get the image to appear on hover:

```
#menu a:hover span.blognav{
position: absolute;
left: -42px;
top: 4px;
width: 190px;
height: 15px;
background: url("AVSprite-menu.png");
background-position: 0px -1px;
}

#menu a:hover span.artnav{
position: absolute;
left: -42px;
top: 40px;
width: 190px;
height: 15px;
background: url("AVSprite-menu.png");
background-position: 0px -39px;
}

#menu a:hover{
color: #29fffa;
}


<div id="menu">
<ul style="list-style-type: none;">
    <li><a href="blog.html">Blog<span class="blognav"></span></a></li>
    <li><a href="about.html"><font color="#29fffa">About</font></a></li>
    <li><a href="art.html">Art<span class="artnav"></span></a></li>
    <li><a href="print.html">Print</a></li>
    <li><a href="web.html">Web</a></li>
    <li><a href="events.html">Events</a></li>
    <li><a href="marketing.html">Marketing</a></li>
    <li><a href="contact.html"><font color="black">Contact</font></a></li>
</div>
```

I'm a beginner, so if there's anything else you see in this code that can help, please let me know. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you make a demo on http://jsfiddle.net/?

Comment: There is no `</ul>`. Put that and try? And, try putting it in a [jsFiddle](http://jsFiddle.net)?

Comment: background: url("AVSprite-menu.png"); = background-image: url("AVSprite-menu.png");

Comment: have you tried setting z-index???

Comment: Praveen - I did miss that, thanks. I added it.

Comment: Scorpio - yes, I did that and despite setting the z-indexes appropriately, the image continues to appear in front of the link. Thanks.

Comment: Jawad, I made that change. I assume because it did nothing that you're just helping me write cleaner code? Thanks.

Comment: Luis - I tried, but my images are local and it's not appearing correctly. I can't find a place on that site to add the images...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/8sxxy/ see if this works for you..I have added z-index

```
a
 {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 5;
}



#menu a:hover span.blognav{
position: absolute;
left: -42px;
top: 4px;
width: 190px;
height: 15px;
background: url("http://s20.postimage.org/ospccawhp/35436251_1_620x433.jpg");
background-position: 0px -1px;
z-index: -5; /* you need to add this too*/
```

}

Comment: Hi Scorpio. I added that code, but it did not move the link to in front of the image. Is it possible I added it in the wrong place? For reference, I have the background image of the website with z-index of -2, the menu links of 2. So I thought leaving/setting the z-index of the hover state image of 0 would work.

Comment: PROGRESS! :D thanks. So the link is showing in front of the image now, but my image placement is moved too high now. Does it have to do with setting position as relative within the a{ code  you provided, when I have the image absolutely positioned in the hover code?

Comment: yeph!!!that not needed you can edit is as you want..your only concern is the z-index for now..

Comment: Scorpio, you're my hero today. Thanks so much!